# Multiplying the probabilities of two events that aren't independent

Tags: probability

If you have two events which aren't independent, say $A$ and $B$, and you multiply $P(A)\cdot P(B)$, why is this probability always smaller than $P(A\mid B)P(B)$?

Comment: It's not. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Simple counterexample: $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, and each have non-zero probability thus: $P(A|B)P(B)=0 \neq P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Thanks, I had misread some information from 'Maths on Trial' where the statement was referring to a particular example. Why is the first probability = 0 in your above answer?

Comment: @Hayley - ah, that's a great book! Note that if A and B are mutually exclusive, its impossible for both of them to happen, hence, if we know B occurred, then A cannot occur.

Comment: Ah of course, **thank you**